# The 4.times closure understanding

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

The gradle build script defined as follows:

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" << {
        println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
```

define 4 different tasks with the names `task1, task2, task3, task4`. So what `4.times` actually is? Is it just a closure which in that case applies 1 argument and called 4 times?

So is it just a syntax sugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4.times` isn't a closure exactly but a loop wrapper. With this statement You *tell* to execute 4 times a given closure. And a given closure in this case is the following piece of code:

```
{ counter ->
    task "task$counter" << {
        println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
```

It creates a task that has an argument passed (*counter*) in it's name. Is that clear?

Here You've [docs](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#times(groovy.lang.Closure)) for *times* method which is defined for *Number* class. As You can see You can invoke it on an instance of number and pass a closure. In this particular case a closure passed created a task.

Comment: Pretty clear. Thank you. It would be better if you complete the answer with a reference to a documentation.

Comment: Have already done it. If the answer satisfies You, please accept it.